# MikTeX: Package installation repair

Tags: errors, miktex, package-options, installing-fonts

I was compiling a TeX file with `marvosym` package - which was not installed in my computer. When it was automatically attempting to install the `marvosym` package, I force closed the program thinking that I will do it directly from the MikTeX package manager. But when I tried to get the package, the package manager showed that 'marvosym' was installed just now - during which I closed it forcefully.

Now, in my package manager, both `install` and `uninstall` options are greyed out and only `properties` option is active. I tried to manually delete all the files (by locating the files using the properties window) to reinstall the entire package. No luck - the install and uninstall options are still greyed out. I tried to run the `.tex` file again - this time it asked for installing the package, and I let it run completely - but I still have an issue where this package is not installed properly and therefore the pdf is not generated.

Is there any way to manually fix this issue - where I would be able to uninstall and install the package properly?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry, but why do think that is a good idea to stop a program in the middle of an installation? Beside this: as you don't say what is not working and which error you get, it is quite difficult to see which part of the package is missing.

Comment: try to `rebuild FNDB` and `Update format` in MiKTeX settings menu, then retry install routine for the package. And I agree with @UlrikeFischer. It's a bad idea to interrupt install procedures.

Comment: Sorry about that. The error is miktex-makemf: the umvs source file could not be found. Running ttf2pk.exe...

:PK font umvs could not be created.

Process exited with errors

Comment: Sounds as if the map file has not been updated. Run on a command line `updmap`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds as if the map file has not been updated. Run on a command line `updmap`.

Remark: This is often necessary -- if you don't kill the installation -- as the admin package manager can not update user map files.

Answer (score 0):

Try running MiKTeX Package Manager (Admin) `mpm_mfc_admin.exe` instead of MiKTeX Package Manager `mpm_mfc.exe`.